# Is it possible to store a variable (int) in SQL to then take effect once a certain date has been reached?

Tags: sql, datetime, int

Is it possible to store a variable in a SQL table which will only take effect once a certain date is reached? The variable is the amount of days that would be added to a date to create a "TargetDate", this variable can be changed by user input but must have an "EffectiveDate" ?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: For example, the variable int could be "20" as in the number of days to be added, this can be changed by the user to say "30". Meaning a date of 02/01/2019 should add 30 days. However the effective date could be 31/01/2019 meaning the the change in value of the int shouldnt take place until after this date. This also means that the value of the int shouldnt effect any dates before the effective date...

Comment: "SQL" (the query language) has no variables to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create a `configuration` table that you store config data in. In your case, one of the items would be `'EFCTV_BUFFER'` as the value in the key column, and (for an example) `'5'` as the number of days in the value column. Then you can reference that key value to select the buffer days value, and add that to whatever date you want.

This allows you to modify it at any time as requested.

You would reference this table in an insert/update trigger on your table where you store your dates. I would suggest having two dates so that the calculation is only done once, unless you need the calculation to be dynamic based upon the current `'EFCTV_BUFFER'` configuration value.